# unable to redirect and display message in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have signup form. I see everything is fine and display properly in the console but I am unable to redirect a page when successfully insert the record as well as display success message. it is also not showing any error like if mail already exist in the database. here is my form

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#registFrm").submit(function () {
           var data = $("#registFrm").serialize();
           signupRecords(data);
           return false;
       });
       function signupRecords(data) {
           $.ajax({
               url: 'signupProcess.php',
               data: data,
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (data) {
                   if(data.code =="200" ) {
                    alert('success :  You have successfully signUp now please login');
                     setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
                            location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
                       }, 5000); 
                  } else {
                      $(".display-error").html("<ul>"+data.msg+"</ul>");
                       $(".display-error").css("display","block");
                  }
              },
               error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                // Your error handling logic here..
                }          
            });
           }
       });
</script>
```

here is my signupProcess.php execution

```
if (empty($errorMSG)) {
$qry = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?');
$qry->bindParam(1, $remail);
$qry->execute();

if ($qry->rowCount() > 0 ) {
    echo json_encode(['code' => 400, 'msg' => 'Email Already Exist']);
     exit;
} else {
     $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name,email,password,mobile) VALUES(:name,:email,:password,:mobile)");
        $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $rname, ':email' => $remail, ':password' => $rpassword, ':mobile' => $rmobile));
        $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($affected_rows == 1) {
            // starts the session created if login info is correct
            echo json_encode(['code' => 200, 'msg' => 'Successfully singUp']);
            exit;
        } else {
            echo json_encode(['code' => 400]);
            exit;
        }
} }else {
        echo json_encode(['code' => 404, 'msg' => $errorMSG]);
    }
```

Comment: have you got alert message?

Comment: No, but i see the success / error message in network console

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pleasae follow my step

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#registFrm").submit(function () {
           var data = $("#registFrm").serialize();
           signupRecords(data);
           return false;
       });
       function signupRecords(data) {
           $.ajax({
               url: 'signupProcess.php',
               data: data,
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (data) {
                   if(data.code ==200 ) {
                    alert('success :  You have successfully signUp now please login');
                     setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
                            location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
                       }, 5000); 
                  } else {
                      $(".display-error").html("<ul>"+data.msg+"</ul>");
                       $(".display-error").css("display","block");
                  }
              },
               error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                // Your error handling logic here..
                }          
            });
           }
       });
</script>
```

Comment: it seems difference is only if(data.code ==200 ) because i use if(data.code =="200" )  but still i don't know why my code was not working. can you tell me whats the problem is there?

Comment: have you remove that double quote because in php code is number and you check with string that's why it not goes to if condition

Comment: can you print your php output here?